# MVC saving items from one list into another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list

OK so to explain this it's best to just step through it.

I have an MVC app for managing sports teams.  This involves creating fixtures and also involves selecting a team to play the fixture.

ATM I have implemented the creation of fixtures and now I am trying to work on getting the user able to select Players from the `TeamRoster` property and save them into the `StartingTeam` list in the `Fixture` object.

At the moment I have a `PickStartingTeam` view and here I want to have each position labeled with a drop down box (or similar) populated with all the `Player` objects in the `Team` `Roster` property that have that `Position` as their `Position`.

Thinking about it I was thinking how you would pass all that view information into the

`FixtureController` method to add them to the `StartingTeam` list and then in turn save the changes to the db etc.

Anyone came across this before?

Many thanks in advance.

J

Comment: well it would be the best not to load data from the database in the view, so you would have to create a placeholder for each position(in view) and populate it on `ActionHandler PickStartingTeam()`

Answer (score 0):

In each of your position drop down box in the `PickStartingTeam` view, you shall give the position a unique position id such as a name, and each `Player`'s id as the selection value.

Then in the `FixtureController` method you shall first get each of the positions value (meaning the `Player`'s id), then assign the `StartingTeam`'s each positions with the selected value. Then in the end, the `StartingTeam` can be saved into the db.